# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 - how to disable city's local name and have label only in preferred or selected language

Tags: javascript, google-maps

does anyone know how to always display single label for a city i.e. disable city's local name if there is equivalent in language that was selected during Google Maps API initialization (e.g. &language=en)?
So to be more specific, not to have **double names** (English and local names displayed **together** on the map) as it happens for Ukraine, China, Japan now, when language=en is selected for Google Maps API?
Thank you in advance for any tips!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Map</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.16&language=en"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.6, 29.5)
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.6, 29.5)
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.16&language=en"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: According to: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.at/2014/11/localization-of-street-addresses-in.html
Its not possible.